# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'RowProxy'

Tags: python, flask, psql

I am trying to implement a log in/sign up/log out element in my python web app. I am using Flask.  I am using bcrypt to hash and salt passwords but keep receiving this error: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'RowProxy'. passwords are definitely getting stored in a hash and salt. But will not allow users to log in.

```
@app.route("/searchPage", methods=['POST','GET'])
def loggingin():
    title = "Search"

    #get request form variables
    username = request.form.get('username')
    if db.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username",{"username": username}).rowcount == 0:
        return render_template("login.html", message="invalid username, please try again.")
    hashed_password = db.execute("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = :username",{"username": username}).fetchone()
    if bcrypt.checkpw(request.form.get('password'), hashed_password):
        return render_template("searchPage.html", title=title)
    else:
        return render_template("login.html", message="Incorrect Password.")
```

And my html is:

```
{% extends "nav.html" %}
{% block body %}
  <main>
    <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
    <h3>Log In </h3>
    <form action="{{ url_for('loggingin') }}" method="POST">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password">
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Log In</button>
    </form>
  </main>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: The problem is this line: `hashed_password = db.execute("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = :username",{"username": username}).fetchone()` You need to get just the password back from the RowProxy. Something like: `hashed_password = db.execute("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = :username",{"username": username}).fetchone()['password']`

Comment: @mechanical_meat: any reason you didn't post that as an answer?

Comment: @LukeWoodward: because I can't test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

db.execute("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = :username",{"username": username}).fetchone()['password']

Differnce was the ['password'] at end of this line. @mechanical_meat